# measure zero implies complement has full measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm doing a problem, where I've reduced the problem to seeing if this claim holds: suppose $R$ has lebesgue outer measure zero. Then $m(D\setminus R)=m(D)$.

For one direction, I just used monoticity of the integral, since $D\setminus R\subset D\implies m(D\setminus R)\leq m(D)$, but am having trouble proving the reverse inequality.

I feel like it's really obvious and I'm just not seeing it. -_-

Comment: It isn't that the complement is equal to the whole set; rather, the complement has *full measure*.

Comment: $m(D) = m(R) + m(D \setminus R) = 0 + m(D \setminus R) = m(D \setminus R)$

Answer (score 2):

The intersection $D \cap R$ is contained in $R$, hence has (Lebesgue) measure zero.

Now, $D \setminus R = D \setminus (D \cap R)$, so 
$$
m(D \setminus R) = m(D \setminus (D \cap R) ) = m(D) - m(D \cap R) = m(D).
$$

P.S.  There is plenty of bad literature on measure theory, and the one and only book I would recommend is Vulikh's *Brief Course in the Theory of Functions of a Real Variable*.

Comment: A very similar alternative is to split $D$ into $(D\setminus R)\cup (R\cap D)$, which are disjoint, and use $m(D)=m(D\setminus R)+m(R\cap D)=m(D\setminus R)+0=m(D\setminus R)$. I'd prefer this since you don't have to account for any sets of infinite measure.

Comment: I'll definitely take this proof, but just out of curiosity, I was wondering if there was a way to complete my way of proving it by showing the reverse inequality? (or is my method of proof for this question totally off?)

Comment: @SamJaques To tell you the truth, I don't see a difference.  If $m(D)$ is finite, no problem.  If $m(D)$ is infinite, you are using this entity arithmetically just like I am.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ray: I heartily concur with Sam Jaques. This proof only works when $D$ has finite measure; $\infty-\infty$ is undefined.

Comment: @CameronBuie, if $m(D)$ is infinite, then the problem boils down to proving that $m(D \setminus R)$ is infinite, as the equality $\infty = \infty$ is not "very defined" either.:)

Comment: @avs: Addition with infinity is always well-defined, but subtraction sometimes isn't. It isn't actually a problem, since $m(D\cap R)\leq m(R)=0$, so even if $m(D)=\infty$, you're doing $\infty-0$, which is well-defined. I'm basically just being pedantic.

Comment: $m(D) = m(D \cap R) + m(D \setminus R)$ is always true in the extended reals. If $m(D \cap R)$ is finite as is the case here, then we can subtract it from both sides (whether or not the other two terms are finite) to get $m(D) - m(D \cap R) = m(D \setminus R)$. Still, no point performing the subtraction when it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Bungo: Excellent point. Rather than saying "this proof only works when," I should have said "$m(D)-m(D\cap R)$ need not be defined in general unless."

Comment: Bourbakists FTW.:)

Answer (score 2):

Your question mentions Lebesgue **outer** measure, and you didn't state explicitly whether $m$ is assumed to be Lebesgue measure, or Lebesgue outer measure.

The answer given by **avs** assumes that $m$ is additive on disjoint sets, which is only guaranteed to be true if $m$ is Lebesgue measure (and therefore $D$ is implicitly assumed to be Lebesgue measurable).

But the result is in fact true if $m$ is Lebesgue outer measure and $D$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb R^d$).

**Proof:**

As you noted, the inequality
$$m(D \setminus R) \leq M(D)$$
follows immediately from monotonicity since $D \setminus R \subset D$.

For the opposite inequality, first note that $D = (D \setminus R)\cup(D \cap R)$. Then by subadditivity,
$$m(D) \leq m(D \setminus R) + m(D \cap R).$$
Now observe that $D \cap R \subset R$, so by monotonicity,
$$m(D \cap R) \leq m(R) = 0.$$
Putting these inequalities together gives us
$$m(D) \leq m(D \setminus R) + m(D \cap R) \leq m(D \setminus R) + m(R) \leq m(D \setminus R)$$
as desired.